# Google Earth crashes when opened

Tags: crash, google-earth

I recently downloaded the Google Earth `.deb` file for 64-bit [from here](http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en-GB/earth/download/ge/agree.html). And I installed it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

And I of course also installed all of the other necessary dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Which Google Earth depends on. But now when I start Google Earth with:

```
google-earth
```

It launches, stays open for about 10 seconds, and then exits. From opening it to it closing this is what I see in Terminal:

```
[0628/171243:ERROR:net_util.cc(2195)] Not implemented reached in bool net::HaveOnlyLoopbackAddresses()
[0628/171244:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171244:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171244:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171244:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/161245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/161245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171245:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171246:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171247:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171247:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171247:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171247:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171247:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171249:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171249:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171249:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171249:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171250:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0628/171253:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171253:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171253:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171253:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0628/171254:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.


Another crash happened while handling crash!
```

I am not sure of the meaning of these error messages, and what I should do about them to stop it from only lasting 10 seconds. So is there anyway I can fix this? Or is this some sort of bug? If so, where should I report it?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
google-earth-stable:
  Installed: 7.1.4.1529-r0
  Candidate: 7.1.4.1529-r0
  Version table:
 *** 7.1.4.1529-r0 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: There may be some prblm with dependies try "dpkg -i mypackage.deb apt-get install --fix-missing"

Comment: @AUmarMukthar: Is that not what I did when I ran `sudo apt-get install -f`, and then installed all of the necessary dependencies for Google Earth?

Comment: You just forced the installation without dependies ..  some software may work but not in every case...

Comment: @AUmarMukthar: Well, it said that it had not properly configured Google Earth, and when installing the other dependencies, it said that it fixed that, and reinstalled it. So you are saying that I should try reinstalling it?

Comment: Have a go see what happens :) [This thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/rDwazZ_Um_I) with the same error message says it is something to do with the Qt stuff bundled with Google Earth, so try installing the 32bit version

Comment: @AUmarMukthar: I tried reinstalling it and that did not work.

Comment: @Wilf: Ok, I have tried getting the 32-bit version, and although I still do get some errors, it works, can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *solution* is to remove (or rename) the `~/.googleearth` directory.

1. Close Google-Earth
2. Rename the directory

   ```
   mv ~/.googleearth ~/old_googleearth
   ```
3. Start Google-Earth and be happy.

---

Well, with Fedora 23 this didn’t help. I had to install the 32 bit version of Google-Earth. At least it works now.

Comment: This worked, when combined with the answer below (wait until fully loaded before even moving the mouse).

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is the message I have received:: `We apologize for the inconvenience, but Google Earth has crashed. This is a bug in the program, and should never happen under normal circumstances. A bug report and debugging data have been written to this text file:
~/.googleearth/crashlogs/crashlog-56b92700.txt`

Comment: @I recommend looking into the mentioned file `~/.googleearth/crashlogs/crashlog-56b92700.txt` and searching for hints there. Maybe even send the crashlog to the Google-Earth developers.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem .. the only way to fix it as far as I know and according to the other forums about googe earth crashing on start up is on start - up just try not to move the mouse and wait for it to be stable (like when the earth has been fully loaded) It works for me .. so give it a try

Comment: Didn’t work for me.

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me either.

Comment: Yes, but also put your mouse cursor somewhere to the middle of the screen (the actual map part of the window). So click to start the program, then immediately move the mouse to the middle of the screen, then don't move it until it's fully loaded. It works for me.

Comment: Either way, this isn't a satisfying solution. It's a *workaround* -- which is definitely helpful! -- but isn't a *fix*.

Comment: I needed to delete ~/.googleearth AND "not move the cursor...". Yup, it's just a workaround :)

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround for me was to disconnect from the Internet before starting the program.

I downloaded the latest version of `google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb` and installed it by Ubuntu Software. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

The better solution to my mind is to install such unstable programs on Virtualbox. But what could I do if the Virtualbox didn't install?

Comment: I did this once and then it starts without crashes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot of a utility available on Ubuntu Software Cente:
[image: Debian package of Google Earth image]

**Steps**:
1. Open Ubuntu software center and search for "googleearth" (no spaces found what I was looking for, with a space between google and earth it yielded something else).

2. After that's the software center should look like the image I've posted. Then on your console/terminal run `make-googleearth-package`.
3. Then run `sudo dpkg -i googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.1.0-1_amd64.deb`  as the console asks you the same after step 1 is done.
4. If some dependencies are unmet run `sudo apt-get update` then run `sudo apt-get -f install`
5. After step 3 run `sudo dpkg -i googleearth_6.0.3.2197+1.1.0-1_amd64.deb`.

This did the trick, no crashes.

Erik's and 7th's solution worked for a few months till today when no matter how much I tried to not-move the mouse or play around with the globe while it loaded and is flying-to, it crashed.

EDIT: Chrome and Google Earth will not run simultaneously on my system, wonder why?

EDIT: Chrome and GEarth work simultaneously now.

Comment: While non of the other proposed solutions worked for me, this one did under Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem, I executed it as `sudo`. In terminal:

```
sudo google-earth
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Excuse me, it doesn't work perfectly. I was using it, I created a route and all was fine but when I tried to open an image it crashed again...

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me.